# How to add another steam library which is on another hdd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, steam

I am completely new to Linux and I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I want to create a steam library on my third HDD in `/dev/sdc2` but how I can do that?

Here is what I get when I type `fdisk -l`

```bash
Disk /dev/loop0: 83,8 MiB, 87896064 bytes, 171672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 255,7 MiB, 268070912 bytes, 523576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 146 MiB, 153026560 bytes, 298880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe9fec952

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 108541672 107515625  51,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       108544000 625139711 516595712 246,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000001

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          718848  71679999  70961152  33,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        71682030 488375999 416693970 198,7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5        71682093 280026966 208344874  99,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6       280029078 488375999 208346922  99,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0CD853A2-561B-49FA-9844-55A57869DF17

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 1953522995 1953258804 931,4G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can i mount hdd permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the proper UUID for your drive you want to mount. You can do that with the `blkid` command (this needs sudo rights to show results):

```
sudo blkid
```

This will yield you an output similar to this:

```
$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for michael: 
/dev/sda2: UUID="2532c426-5e7d-44f1-a8b4-69df83084b66" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4babc94e-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="17.10" UUID="e99a2f32-9120-4c77-96da-42a8dde6e794" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="4babc94e-03"
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="Archiv" UUID="01CD98D69CBEDDB0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0014fc58-06"
/dev/sdb7: LABEL="Backup" UUID="01CD98D83C78F3D0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0014fc58-07"
/dev/sdc3: LABEL="HTTP" UUID="E8FC872CFC86F3DA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2892f529-03"
/dev/sdc5: LABEL="DEVEL" UUID="2632B65632B62AA7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2892f529-05"
/dev/sdc6: LABEL="games2" UUID="456f4f92-97ab-48c3-ac95-45a54baa709f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2892f529-06"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="games1" UUID="79672110-c2c1-4538-926d-80e861613c1e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6b8a3ad1-01"
```

What you want it the UUID for the drive you want to mount then you can edit your `/etc/fstab` file with nano or something and add a line like this (just use the UUID your drive has and switch out `ext4` for `ntfs` if your drive is formatted in NTFS file system):

```
UUID=79672110-c2c1-4538-926d-80e861613c1e /games1         ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Here an example of how I would mount the backup drive in my example above:

```
UUID=01CD98D83C78F3D0                     /backup         ntfs-3g errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

After that you need to reboot to make the settings work. Note that you can choose the mount-point yourself, if you do it like above the drive is mounted to `/games1`. After that all you now need to do is fire up Steam and install a game where you can choose on which drive/path you want to perform the installation. See also the [fstab documentation here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more information on mount-options.